# Kubernetes Dashboard: Display Ingress URLs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

i have the `kubernetes-dashboard` running and i am accessing it from outside the cluster using `NGINX Ingress Controller`. Everything works fine, after logging in, i can see all deployments, etc.

I have several applications deployed, which are made accessible from outside using the ingress ressources **under a specified URL + Path**. So one app is accessible for example under https://mydomain.de/app, which is specified in its `Ingress Ressource`.

I'm asking myself now, if i can configure the kubernetes dashboard / the ingress ressource in a way so that these URLs are visible in the Dashboard UI.

There is a Section for the `Ingresses`, but under `Endpoints` it only shows an IP.
It would be really great if there was a way to display the URL + Path for each ingress, instead.

Thanks in Advance guys

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality by defaut not in kubernetes-dashboard neither in nginx.
The only solution that quickly comes to mind is to try use [NGINX Amplify Custom Dashboards](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-amplify-doc/blob/master/amplify-guide.md)

Check

- [Introducing Custom Dashboards in NGINX Amplify](https://www.nginx.com/blog/custom-dashboards-nginx-amplify)
- [Using NGINX Amplify Custom Dashboards and Filters for Better NGINX Monitoring](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-amplify-custom-dashboards-filters/)
- [Setting Up NGINX Amplify in 10 Minutes](https://www.nginx.com/blog/setting-up-nginx-amplify-in-10-minutes/)